# Make a div transparent but not the image inside

Tags: html, css, image, background

I want to have a div that has an image inside, but with the div and background being completely transparent, giving the impression the image exists alone, with the elements behind the background of the div appearing.

I've tried using rgba in several ways, such as `background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5);` but all of these end up leaving a white background on the div when set to total transparency.

How can I implement this?

EDIT
Here is a picture:
[image: This is a crop of the UI screen. The red button is the image and the white is the div backgroud.]

How can I make the red button appear as normal, but be able to see what is behind the white part?

My HTML is as such:

```
<div id="transparent-background">
    <img src="./images/ui/chat.gif" class="arrow-button"/>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your question might not be so clear. Do you want a gif image to be shiny, and you want its background to be transparent? If that's the case, all you have to do, is to edit/change your gif file (to have a transparent background). It has nothing to do with the `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this CSS for your DIV:

```
#transparent-background {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: found the problem. Turns out there was ANOTHER div with a white background behind the first one. That's why setting to transparent was not showing the screen behind it. D'OH!